# Could not load file or assembly System.Linq.Dynamic.Core Version=1.0.15.0

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-1.0, system.linq.dynamic

Added  System.Linq.Dynamic.Core Version=1.0.15.0 from nuget in current Asp.net core 1.1 project. Added required moethods in library but when method is called error is thrown as "Could not load file or assembly 'System.Linq.Dynamic.Core, Version=1.0.15.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0f07ec44de6ac832'. The system cannot find the file specified"

Tried to restore the package but no use

Comment: This should just work. Can you take a look at this example project: https://github.com/StefH/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core/tree/master/src-console/System.Linq.Dynamic.Core.ConsoleTestApp ?